Consolidate column in Google Sheets
I have 2 columns (this is a timesheet) - the first column lists various project someone has worked each day  - the second the number of hours / minutes they have spent that day (example below)









SBL.008 Heartwired
5.00


SBL.008 Heartwired
9.00


SBS.030 NYCFC - Soaring Tetris
3.00


SBS.030 NYCFC - Soaring Tetris
8.50


SBS.036 H&S Frankfurt - Eur
5.00


SBS.036 H&S Frankfurt - Eur
3.00



I would like to create a weekly analysis showing the total number of hours per project
ie









SBL.008 Heartwired
14:00


SBS.030 NYCFC - Soaring Tetris
11:50



Can someone help me with a script or formula please?

Please provide a minimal reproducible example like markdown tables containing your sample input data.

From your given data SBS.030 NYCFC - Soaring Tetris 8.50, does 8.50 stand for 8 hours and a half ( 8 hours 30 mins) or 8 hours and 50 minutes?

It should be 30 minutes (so half an hour) I can adjust how we calculate time at a later point

Thank you for your response - I will see if I can work out how to do that tomorrow!

Use SUMIFS with BYROW
Formula:
You may use:
=LET(a, UNIQUE(TOCOL(A1:A,1)),
     b, BYROW(a,LAMBDA(x,SUMIF(A1:A,x,B1:B))),
     c, BYROW(b,LAMBDA(y,y/24)),
     HSTACK(a,c))

EU Version:
=LET(a; UNIQUE(TOCOL(A1:A;1));
     b; BYROW(a;LAMBDA(x;SUMIF(A1:A;x;B1:B)));
     c; BYROW(b;LAMBDA(y;y/24));
     HSTACK(a;c))

Output:









SBL.008 Heartwired
0.583333333333333


SBS.030 NYCFC - Soaring Tetris
0.479166666666667


SBS.036 H&S Frankfurt - Eur
0.333333333333333



Afterwards, highlight the output values and go to:
Format > Number > Custom Number Format
and enter hh:mm. The output will then turn into:









SBL.008 Heartwired
14:00


SBS.030 NYCFC - Soaring Tetris
11:30


SBS.036 H&S Frankfurt - Eur
08:00



References

BYROW
SUMIFS
LET
HSTACK


Thank you for your help - when using the above code i get this message  Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '=' line: 1 file: Code.gs

I am a complete novice with Google - so I am sure I am doing something very basic wrong

@Marcidee this is not a Google Apps Script Code but a Google Sheets Formula which you will place on the actual spreadsheet and not on the Code.gs. You did mention on your post: "Can someone help me with a script or formula please?"

thank you for providing this formula - it does consolidate all projects in column A - however doesn't add up the hours correctly?

It is because it is in decimal form. Therefore, 11.5 is 11 hours and a half. Let me try and convert it.

I have updated the answer posted above and added a conversion formula to convert the hours data into days since it is the prerequisite for the number formatting for hh:mm.

Thank you for your  I am not getting the correct results still: Data I am using
SBL.008 Heartwired 3.00
SBL.008 Heartwired 5.00
SBL.008 Heartwired 7.50
SBS.030 NYCFC - Soaring Tetris 9.00
SBS.036 H&S Frankfurt  5.00
SBS.036 H&S Frankfurt 3.00
SBS.036 H&S Frankfurt  8.50   initial results
SBL.008 Heartwired 0.6727430556
SBS.030 NYCFC - Soaring Tetris 0.390625
SBS.036 H&S Frankfurt  0.7161458333 when I reformat the results to HH:MM i get
SBL.008 Heartwired 16:10
SBS.028.RCB Real Life Chat 00:00
SBS.030 NYCFC - Soaring Tetris 09:23
SBS.036 H&S Frankfurt 17:13

On my end, I get |
SBL.008 Heartwired - 14:30 |
SBS.030 NYCFC - Soaring Tetris - 09:00 |
SBS.036 H&S Frankfurt - 16:30

Is it possible that you have other data as well? you should adjust the range since I noticed that there are other entries not included in your sample output.

In my message yesterday I removed anything that had a value of zero as there were too many characters to fit into the comment - is thee anyway in Stackflow to send the data so you can see what I have done?  I have tried numerous ways of applying the formula by manipulating the data and formatting prior to running the formula without success
